# error 102, need to insert date and time into table sql

Tags: sql-server, date

I am getting a syntax error near  " : "  on the first line of the VALUES part of the statement. If I remove this, the same I true for all subsequent lines. How can I fix this error?

Data type I have set for the date is, date.
Data type I have set for the time is, time.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ActualTripStopInfo]
       ([TripNumber], [Date], [ScheduledStartTime],
        [StopNumber], [ScheduledArrivalTime],
        [ActualStartTime], [ActualArrivalTime],
        [NumberOfPassengerIn], [NumberOfPassengerOut])
VALUES
    (1, 2021-01-01, 04:30:00, 3, 05:00, 04:30:00, 05:00:00, 10, 10),
    (2, 2021-01-01, 05:00:00, 8, 06:15, 05:00:00, 06:15:00, 15, 15),
    (3, 2021-01-03, 06:00:00, 1, 06:15, 06:00:00, 06:15:00, 25, 25),
    (4, 2021-01-02, 05:45:00, 5, 06:15, 05:45:00, 06:15:00, 20, 20),
    (5, 2021-01-03, 08:00:00, 2, 08:20, 08:00:00, 08:20:00, 32, 32),
    (6, 2021-01-04, 12:45:00, 10, 13:30, 12:45:00, 13:30:00, 11, 11),
    (7, 2021-01-03, 16:15:00, 2, 16:50, 16:15:00, 16:50:00, 5, 5),
    (8, 2021-01-05, 20:00:00, 1, 20:15, 20:00:00, 20:15:00, 10, 10),
    (9, 2021-01-05, 08:15:00, 3, 08:45, 08:15:00, 08:45:00, 28, 28),
    (10, 2021-01-04, 07:30:00, 4, 07:50, 07:30:00, 07:50:00, 35, 35);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the dates and times

```
...
VALUES
(1,'2021-01-01','04:30:00',3,'05:00','04:30:00','05:00:00',10,10),
(2,'2021-01-01','05:00:00',8,'06:15','05:00:00','06:15:00',15,15),
...
```